# Getting ERROR: Unable to provision MSA id automatically. Please pass them in as parameters and try again

Tags: azure, bots, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to setup a BOT project using Visual Studio. I am following the instructions in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-enterprise-template-deployment?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

During deployment when I run the command

```
msbot clone services --name "MyBotName" --luisAuthoringKey "abcd" --folder "DeploymentScripts\msbotClone" --location "westus"
```

After sometime I get the following error
ERROR: Unable to provision MSA id automatically. Please pass them in as parameters and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You can now do it like below from cli (get the appid and secret by manually creating app using the azure preview feature or https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/)

```
msbot clone services --name "" --luisAuthoringKey "" --folder "DeploymentScripts\msbotClone" --location "" --appId "" --appSecret ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and there are an opening issue for this problem [Can't create bot registration](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/issues/596).

The problem happen when the script try to create new chatbot by the command 'az bot create' without passing appid and password.

for me as a temporary solution I change the command and passing appid and password.

Find your npm modules msbot folder (usually at `C:\Users\{{username}}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\msbot\bin`), edit `msbot-clone-services.js` and find createBot() function (around line 687) and edit the command to:

```
let command = `az bot create -g ${args.groupName} --name ${args.name} --kind webapp --location ${args.location} --insights-location "${args.insightsRegion}" --appid "your_appid" --password "your_password"`
```

You can find or create your app at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/